# Same attribute with empty value

Tags: node.js, express

How can I get a field value if the value is empty?

```
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="remarks"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="remarks"></td>
    </tr>
```

For example when I do a POST, if the second name attribute and first remark is empty:

```
{name: [ 'Kelvin']
remarks: [ 'help me' ]}
```

How can I get this:

```
{name: [ 'Kelvin', '' ],
remarks: [ '', 'help me' ]}
```

With this I would know the second name attribute and first remark is empty when doing a loop.

---

UPDATE:

I problem I found out is because of enctype="multipart/form-data" form and express multer.

Comment: You can make the inputs arrays as in `name="name[]"` and `name="remarks[]"`.  Does this not work?

Comment: I tried, it give me the same result.